# Homogeneous System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find The General Solution Of This Systems:

1- $Y^{\prime}=AY$ ; $A=\begin{bmatrix}4 & -9\\4 & -8 \ \end{bmatrix}$.

2- $Y^{\prime}=AY$ ; $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -2\\2 & -3 \ \end{bmatrix}$.

I got this answer:

1- $Y=\alpha_1\begin{bmatrix}3 \\2 \ \end{bmatrix}e^{-2t}+\alpha_2(\begin{bmatrix}3 \\2 \ \end{bmatrix}t+\begin{bmatrix}{1\over 2} \\0 \ \end{bmatrix})e^{-2t}$.

but my teacher got:

$Y=\alpha_1\begin{bmatrix}3 \\2 \ \end{bmatrix}e^{-2t}+\alpha_2(\begin{bmatrix}3 \\2 \ \end{bmatrix}t+\begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \ \end{bmatrix})e^{-2t}$.

---

2- I got:

$Y=\alpha_1\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \ \end{bmatrix}e^{-2t}+\alpha_2(\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \ \end{bmatrix}t+\begin{bmatrix}{3\over 2} \\1 \ \end{bmatrix})e^{-2t}$.

or

$Y=\alpha_1\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \ \end{bmatrix}e^{-2t}+\alpha_2(\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \ \end{bmatrix}t+\begin{bmatrix}{1\over 2} \\0 \ \end{bmatrix})e^{-2t}$.

or

$Y=\alpha_1\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \ \end{bmatrix}e^{-2t}+\alpha_2(\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \ \end{bmatrix}t+\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\{3\over 2} \ \end{bmatrix})e^{-2t}$.

I think the last three answers all is true and sure there are another answers,

but my teacher got:

$Y=\alpha_1\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \ \end{bmatrix}e^{-2t}+\alpha_2(\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \ \end{bmatrix}t+\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\1 \ \end{bmatrix})e^{-2t}$.

so are my answers true? or the answers of my techer?

I try to check if my teacher's answer make $Y^{\prime}=AY$ or not, and I got "not", but I want to make sure from my answer then tell my teacher :).

Thanks.

Comment: Check your answers by derivation.

Comment: did you try to check the original equation for alpha1=0, alpha2=1?

Comment: Yeah, I check my answer, and got $Y^{\prime}=AY$, and check my teacher answer but don't got  $Y^{\prime}=AY$. but I want to make sure then tell my answers to my teacher, because I fear him:(

Comment: I checked the first in my head, your answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I well be talk with my teacher, I don' t be afraid :) "sorry I don't speak English well".

Comment: yeah, I find $Y'$ then find $AY$ and got $Y'=AY$ in my answer, but i don't got  it in my teacher answer